# Tooltip showing twice

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tooltip, mousehover

I'm showing a `ToolTip` on a certain button's `MouseHover` event. If I go over it once it works but if I leave, wait for the tooltip to disapear and come back on the button, it appears twice. I tried cancelling it on `MouseLeave` but it still appear twice the seocnd time.

```
Private Sub someButton_MouseHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles someButton.MouseHover

   Dim tooltipSearch As New ToolTip()
   tooltipSearch.Show("I'm a tooltip"), someButton)

End Sub

 Private Sub someButton_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles someButton.MouseLeave

    Dim toolTip As New ToolTip()
    toolTip.GetToolTip(someButton)
    toolTip.Hide(someButton)
    toolTip.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You are using the ToolTip in a wrong way. You should read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) again ;). I also would suggest you to just drag the tooltip on your form, just like any other control.

Comment: Oooh I always used it like this... I should read the doc indeed.

Comment: @Styxxy I dragged it like another control and it works now.. you can formulate and answer and explain that I should not use the tooltip like this so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `ToolTip` not in the way it should be used (also look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) :) ). It is just like any other control, start by dragging it onto your form (like you do with other controls).

If you have no dynamic text to be displayed in your tooltip, you can easily set the text in your constructor, using the method [`SetToolTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip.aspx). If you do want some dynamic text, you can use this method in your `MouseHover` event.

Apart from that, you shouldn't do anything anything else. Just set the right delays on your tooltip and it should work all fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub someButton_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
                                  Handles someButton.MouseHover
  ToolTip1.SetToolTip(someButton, "My name is Steve chamba from south Africa")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Steve, welcome to Stack Overflow.  It'd be good if you could provide some more detail to why it works - this helps others figure out what went wrong and how not to do something.  Could you do this please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer about dragging the ToolTip control to the form is great. There is a subtlety with Button controls though. They seem to automatically set the tool tip to the text of the button, so if you also call `ToolTip1.SetToolTip(myButton, "Button Text")` then dot-net draws two copies of the tool tip text when you hover over the button.